# preg_match code for japanese kana with alphanumeric?

Tags: php, preg-match

preg_match code for japanese kana,alphanumeric with single or double byte space.

```
if (!preg_match("[ァ-ヶー ][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", $name)) {
return 'display err msg。';
```

}

but its not working.

instead of above code below code is working, but want to include single and double byte white space.

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?:\xE3\x82[\xA1-\xBF]|\xE3\x83[\x80-\xB6]|\xE3\x83\xBC)+$/', $this -> data[$this->name]['kana'])) {
         return 'display err msg';}
```

is there any chance?... help me..

Answer (score 0):

I would use htmlentities() and the result in a preg_match() ,using simbol range...
http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/japanesechartkatakana.html

Comment: instead of above code below code is working, but want to include single and double byte white space.

if (!preg_match('/^(?:\xE3\x82[\xA1-\xBF]|\xE3\x83[\x80-\xB6]|\xE3\x83\xBC)+$/', $this -> data[$this->name]['kana'])) {
         return 'display err msg';}